# The print method and GIL

Tags: python, multithreading, gil

I have a multi-threading program and have faced an interesting phenomenon recently.

If I call the `print` method in the worker of a thread, the program turns very reactive. There's no big trick, just calling the `print` method resolves everything.

I have recently read an article about Python's Global Interpreter Lock aka GIL and it was saying the GIL is released once an I/O bound stuff is executed. Do you think the `print` call is also an I/O bound?

I would really like to make my program reactive but it is obviously awkward to dump data on the stdout while it's running. So I tried to redirect the output to `/dev/null` but it didn't resolve the issue:

```
with contextlib.redirect_stdout(None):
    print('')
```

I would appreciate if you have an idea so that I can reproduce the same effect with the following call but without dumping anything:

```
print('')
```

As far as I see the phenomenon, the GIL is released while the interpreter is working for `print('')`. Maybe I need such a short break which releases me from the GIL.

This is just for your information but I have tried to call the following method:

```
print('', end='', flush=True)
```

Of course, it didn't dump anything but my program turned a bit jaggy and it looked to be the thread had occupied the execution time so other threads were running very infrequently.

**Update**

If I call `usleep(1)` of QThread expecting to let it sleep for 1 us, then it waits much more than I specified. For example. the thread worker runs every 1 ms which is very slow because I was expecting to run it in the microsecond order. Calling `print('')` makes the thread running in a few microseconds order. In this meaning, I call it reactive.

**Update**

I feel something is drugging the execution time of the thread but it's not `usleep` or `time.sleep()`. However, I've faced a fact that `print` can kick the blocker away. So I would like to know what is actually kicking away the blocker.

Comment: `print` is a relatively slow function, so it can potentially change the timing of functions that use it. Be careful as you may be just luckily hiding a race condition because of the addition of the `print` function.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I understand your advice but I'm not sticking with the print method. I just need a way which makes the thread fast. Originally I tried to call `uleep(1)` of PyQt's QThread class, but it seemed to be sleeping much more than I specified. So I removed the `usleep` and realized the thread turns very reactive just calling `print('')`.

Comment: What do you mean by reactive?

Comment: If I call `usleep(1)` of QThread expecting to let it sleep for 1 us, then it waits much more than I specified. For example. the thread worker runs every 1 ms which is very slow because I was expecting to run it in the microsecond order. Calling `print('')` makes the thread running in a few microseconds oder. In this meaning I call it reactive.

Comment: I feel something is drugging the execution time of the thread but it's not `usleep` or `time.sleep()`. However, I've faced a fact that `print` can kick the blocker away. So I would like to know what is actually kicking away the blocker.

Comment: Try `time.sleep(0)`; that should just yield the GIL then immediately queue up to reacquire it. That said, if you're on Windows, the WinAPI functions for blocking waits (which the GIL and all other blocking timed waits are built around) don't have very good granularity; if it sleeps at all, and the other thread doesn't release the GIL on its own, odds are it will take a few milliseconds to come back.

Answer (score 2):

So there are two things happening here. First, for the GIL itself, most of the I/O functions will release it just before calling into platform code, so a `print` call will definitely release it. This will naturally let the runtime schedule another thread.

Second, for `usleep`, this function is guaranteed to sleep *at least* as many microseconds as you ask for, but is pretty much not going to sleep *less than* the duration of the OS scheduler tick. On Linux this is often running at 1,000 Hz, 250 Hz, or 100 Hz, but can vary quite a bit.

Now, if you want something more granular than that, there's the [`nanosleep`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/nanosleep) call which will "busy-wait" for delays shorter than 2 ms instead of calling into the kernel.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! I think I can make a try having the information. I'll accept your answer once I confirmed the outcome. Thank you again!